# cmake link subdirectories together

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I have the following folder hieararchy in my QT project and I need to use some classes of the Utility folder in the classes of the ImageProcessing folder.
[image]

CMAKE file of Utilities:

```
file(GLOB Utilities_Files *.cpp *.h *.hpp)

# add component
add_library(Utilities ${Utilities_Files})

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Utilities ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

CMAKE file of ImageProcessing:

```
file(GLOB ImageProcessing_FILES *.cpp *.h *.hpp)

# add component
add_library(ImageProcessing ${ImageProcessing_FILES})

include_directories(../Utilities)
target_link_libraries(ImageProcessing Utilities)


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(ImageProcessing ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

when I try to include classes from Utilities in classes of ImageProcessing:

```
#include "Utilities/className.h"
```

The compiler always fails.. Not sure why? It seems there is something missed or misunderstood.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `include_directories(../Utilities)` adds the path `../Utilities` to include directories. However, you include `Utilities/className.h` in the source file which makes the compiler search for files `./Utilities/className.h` and `../Utilities/Utilities/className.h`.

Remove one of the `Utilities` in either `include_directories` or `#include`.

```
include_directories(..)
```

or

```
#include "className.h"
```

Comment: In either case, it fixed the compiler issue but now when I use ClassName.something in the class where it's included, the compiler says "ClassName has not been declared". weird no?

Comment: @Maystro: Error  "ClassName has not been declared" is unrelated to problem in finding include file. Fill another question, and provide code which cause that error.

Comment: @Maystro Tsyvarev is right, it’s a different problem (not related with CMake) and a new question should be opened for it. Also please consider [accepting my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the tick on the left side.

Comment: @Melebius, Thanks for your help.